# Clone many cross-referencing documents in a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have an application for users to build a hierarchical assembly of input components.  The tree is too large to store in a single document (think every screw in a car), so each branch and leaf is a separate document with cross-references to keep the hierarchy.

```
{ '_id': 1, 'name': 'screw', 'partnum': 'ABC123' },
{ '_id': 2, 'name': 'mountingplate', 'partnum': 'CBA321' },
{ '_id': 3, 'name': 'widget', 'children': [1,2] }
```

One of the functions will let users clone an existing model to play with rather than starting from scratch (if I replace all the aluminum struts with titanium, how does the weight and cost change?).  So I have a separate 'models' collection, and each component has a 'modelid' field.  So to clone an existing model, the best I can come up with so far using pymongo is:

```
conversionmap = {}
#replace the modelid and individual component id
for doc in db.components.find({'modelid': oldmodelid}):
    conversionmap[doc['_id']] = bson.ObjectId()
    doc['_id'] = conversionmap[doc['_id']]
    doc['modelid'] = newmodelid
    db.components.insert_one(doc)
#go through a second time to update all the cross references
for doc in db.components.find({'modelid': newmodelid}):
    updatecrossrefs(doc, conversionmap)
    db.components.update_one(doc['_id'], doc)
```

That's potentially an awful lot of insert/update queries!  If I read the entire list into memory, I could combine the insert and update steps into one, but I'm not sure how practical that is.  Bulk writes seem similarly perilous.

Is there a sensible way to do this with server-side javascript or the aggregation pipeline?  I won't know the full structure of these documents, which near as I can tell makes using `$project` impossible.  Would using multiple collections make things easier? (And is there some overhead to using a hundred different collections?)

EDIT: An acceptable answer might well include "stop using mongo and go find a real RDBMS!" provided it results in substantially fewer separate queries while still not reading a bunch into memory.